# Attribute error in PPO algorithm for Cartpole gym environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, openai-gym, policy-gradient-descent

I'm trying to run the code from here (Github link on this page): https://keras.io/examples/rl/ppo_cartpole/

I'm getting an attribute error in the training section from `observation = observation.reshape(1,-1)` which says "'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'".

It seems that `observation` is currently `env.reset()` which is a tuple of an array (initial observation) and an empty dictionary (info). I've tried applying this to just the array using `observation[0].reshape(1,-1)` or `env.reset[0]` but that throws up a "too many values to unpack (expected 4)" error two lines later. Does anyone know how I can fix this without messing up the rest of the code?

Minimal reproducible example as requested

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import gym
import scipy.signal

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")

steps_per_epoch = 4000
epochs = 30
hidden_sizes = (64, 64)

observation_dimensions = env.observation_space.shape[0]
num_actions = env.action_space.n

observation_input = keras.Input(shape=(observation_dimensions,), dtype=tf.float32)
logits = mlp(observation_input, list(hidden_sizes) + [num_actions], tf.tanh, None)
actor = keras.Model(inputs=observation_input, outputs=logits)

observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset(), 0, 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Initialize the sum of the returns, lengths and number of episodes 
      for each epoch
    sum_return = 0
    sum_length = 0
    num_episodes = 0

    for t in range(steps_per_epoch):
            if render:
                env.render()

            observation = observation.reshape(1, -1)
            logits, action = sample_action(observation)
            observation_new, reward, done, _ = env.step(action[0].numpy())
            episode_return += reward
            episode_length += 1

        # Get the value and log-probability of the action
        value_t = critic(observation)
        logprobability_t = logprobabilities(logits, action)

        # Store obs, act, rew, v_t, logp_pi_t
        buffer.store(observation, action, reward, value_t, logprobability_t)

        # Update the observation
        observation = observation_new

        # Finish trajectory if reached to a terminal state
        terminal = done
        if terminal or (t == steps_per_epoch - 1):
            last_value = 0 if done else critic(observation.reshape(1, -1))
            buffer.finish_trajectory(last_value)
            sum_return += episode_return
            sum_length += episode_length
            num_episodes += 1
            observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset(), 0, 0
```

where

```
def mlp(x, sizes, activation=tf.tanh, output_activation=None):
    # Build a feedforward neural network
    for size in sizes[:-1]:
        x = layers.Dense(units=size, activation=activation)(x)
    return layers.Dense(units=sizes[-1], activation=output_activation)(x)
```

and

```
@tf.function
def sample_action(observation):
    logits = actor(observation)
    action = tf.squeeze(tf.random.categorical(logits, 1), axis=1)
    return logits, action
```

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. Not as a picture. Use three tildas to wrap your code block

Comment: Have tried to do that, hope its enough as the whole code is quite long with a lot of different components so not sure if i've got everything. Here's the whole thing: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/rl/ppo_cartpole.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`env.reset()`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/dcd185843a62953e27c2d54dc8c2d647d604b635/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py#L190) returns `observation` and `info`, where `info` is empty. In our case, you can simply do:

```py
observation, info = env.reset()
```

## Edit:

When the environment is reset via `env.reset()` it returns only `observation, info`, but when you make steps in the environment via `env.step(...)`, it returns 4 variables: `observation, reward, done, info` instead. Your typical training loop should look like this:

```py
for episode in range(10):
    observation, info = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
         observation, reward, done, info = env.step(...)
```

## Fixed code

It turns out that CartPole environment returns 5 variables instead of 4 when using `env.step()`. Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import gym
import scipy.signal

def mlp(x, sizes, activation=tf.tanh, output_activation=None):
    # Build a feedforward neural network
    for size in sizes[:-1]:
        x = layers.Dense(units=size, activation=activation)(x)
    return layers.Dense(units=sizes[-1], activation=output_activation)(x)

@tf.function
def sample_action(observation):
    logits = actor(observation)
    action = tf.squeeze(tf.random.categorical(logits, 1), axis=1)
    return logits, action

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")

steps_per_epoch = 4000
epochs = 30
hidden_sizes = (64, 64)

observation_dimensions = env.observation_space.shape[0]
num_actions = env.action_space.n

observation_input = keras.Input(shape=(observation_dimensions,), dtype=tf.float32)
logits = mlp(observation_input, list(hidden_sizes) + [num_actions], tf.tanh, None)
actor = keras.Model(inputs=observation_input, outputs=logits)



for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Initialize the sum of the returns, lengths and number of episodes 
    #  for each epoch
    observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset()[0], 0, 0 # <-- HERE

    sum_return = 0
    sum_length = 0
    num_episodes = 0

    for t in range(steps_per_epoch):
        if render:
            env.render()

        observation = observation.reshape(1, -1)
        logits, action = sample_action(observation)
        observation_new, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action[0].numpy())  # <- EDIT 2 HERE
        episode_return += reward
        episode_length += 1

    # Get the value and log-probability of the action
    value_t = critic(observation)
    logprobability_t = logprobabilities(logits, action)

    # Store obs, act, rew, v_t, logp_pi_t
    buffer.store(observation, action, reward, value_t, logprobability_t)

    # Update the observation
    observation = observation_new

    # Finish trajectory if reached to a terminal state
    terminal = done
    if terminal or (t == steps_per_epoch - 1):
        last_value = 0 if done else critic(observation.reshape(1, -1))
        buffer.finish_trajectory(last_value)
        sum_return += episode_return
        sum_length += episode_length
        num_episodes += 1
        observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset()[0], 0, 0 # <-- Here
```

Comment: This is the same as doing `env.reset()[0]`?  I still get the "too many values to unpack (expected 4)" on the line ```observation_new, reward, done, _ = env.step(action[0].numpy())```

`env.step(action[0].numpy())` returns something like this ```(array([-0.03344859,  0.22586484,  0.03981624, -0.27407527], dtype=float32), 1.0, False, False, {})```

Have tried `observation_new, reward, done, _, _` but then it seems to loop through a few times and give me "'tuple' object has no attribute 'reshape'" again

Comment: It is the same, but you are a little bit incorrect here. When the environment is reset via `env.reset()` it returns only `observation, info`, but when you make steps in the environment via `env.step(...)`, it returns 4 variables: `observation, reward, done, info` instead. I have add the loop to illustrate the thing in the answer, please kindly check.

Comment: Sure, thanks. How can I fix the unpacking error then? I have added more to the example in my question.

Comment: You code is still missing some functions for it to run properly, but I modified two lines indicated by `# <- HERE` for you, please check.

Comment: yeah I know it doesn't have `critic`, `buffer`, `logprobability` etc. but they aren't really relevant to the error? 

With your edits I'm still getting the "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)"  on the line `observation_new, reward, done, _ = env.step(action[0].numpy())`

The full code is copied and pasted from here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/rl/ppo_cartpole.py

Comment: I just realized that [`env.step(...)`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/dcd185843a62953e27c2d54dc8c2d647d604b635/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py#L188) returns 5 inputs instead of 4. Can you try the updated code

Comment: Ahhh it works! Thanks so much. Yes was trying to say it returned 5 so I did try `observation_new, reward, done, _, _` but I didn't combine it with `env.reset()[0]`. Together they work. Thank you again.